# AngularJS NgChange not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

in Angularjs i have added the following select control that listen for a change event

```
<select ng-model="Ruoli" ng-options="ruolo.Nome for ruolo in ruoli" class="form-control" ng-change="setNotRuolo(Ruoli.Id)"></select>
```

When i select an item the function

> setNotRuolo()

is correctly called but when i change the items using the key down on the keyboard that function isn't called.

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunker? That will help identify the problem

Comment: This is a known bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4216#issuecomment-25872117

Solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/ccL4Y1LWSOz22o6SZHLS?p=preview

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2616 Which version of angular do you use? This happened just in firefox, but also in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Issue which has already been discussed at **[GitHub](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4216#issuecomment-25872117)**

Just take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/74/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <label for="browsers">Pick A Name:</label>
    <form name="myForm">
        <select dselect required id="browsers" ng-model="selectValue" ng-options="browser for browser in browsers">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>You Selected: {{selectValue || "You didn't pick"}}</div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.browsers = ['Manu', 'Mathew', 'Sunny'];
    $scope.submit = function () {
        alert("submit");
    }
});
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Sunny") !== -1) {
    app.directive("select", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            require: "?ngModel",
            scope: false,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) {
                    return;
                }
                element.bind("keyup", function () {
                    element.trigger("change");
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This fails to answer the question in any way.